# Can max_children of 0 be used in elasticsearch has_child query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to select parents that don't have any children matching a particular set of criteria. I thought that if I did:

```
        {
          "has_child": {
            "max_children": 0,
            "type": "event",
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "cs_e": "eventF"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "should": [],
                      "mustNot": []
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [],
                "mustNot": []
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

then this would return me parents who had a maximum of 0 children - ie the parents that don't match. Curiously, however, I do get one parent back from the query, and that parent has one child that matches.

Is this expected? (Possibly I have messed up somewhere or misunderstood)?

Many thanks!

Comment: question is bit unclear IMO, some sample documents and mapping would help a lot in understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve. Also parent and child documents can be queried independently

Answer (score 0):

Found this cite in "Breaking changes in ES 5.0":

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_search_changes.html

> When the max_children parameter was set to 0 on the has_child query
>   then there was no upper limit on how many child documents were allowed
>   to match. Now, 0 really means that zero child documents are allowed.
>   If no upper limit is needed then the max_children parameter shouldn’t
>   be specified at all.

so in ES >5.0 it should work, but for some reasons max_children=0 really doesn't work in 5.3.0